# Edit Button not working Error: localhost redirected too many times

Tags: php, mysql

maybe you can help, been stuck on this all day. I don't understand for the life of me why when I click the edit button it redirects me to my index.php and gives the error of localhost redirected too many times.

I used this code which works perfect, with no errors. This is a list of my products that can then be deleted or edited.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
 
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

require_once 'header.php';

require_once 'previewheader.php';

if( isset($_POST['delete'])){
    
    if($sql = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id = ?"))
            {
            $sql->bind_param("i", $_POST['productid']);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->close();
            }
            else{
                echo ("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Error: There was an error while deleting product</div>");   
            }
            echo ("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully deleted product</div>");

}


$sql    = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = $con->query($sql); 

if( $result->num_rows > 0)

{ 
?>
    
<h2 style="margin-left: -29.5%;">List of all Products</h2>
    <table style="margin-left: -30%;" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Category</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Image</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Name</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Price</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Description</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px;">Product Details</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Specifications</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Information</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px;">Links</td>
            <td width="70px">Delete</td>
            <td width="70px">EDIT</td>
        </tr>
        
        
<?php
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";  //added
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='". $row['product_id']."' name='productid' />"; //added
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['category'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['productname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['price'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['description'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['details'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['spec_1'] . "<br>" . $row['spec_2'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_3'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_4'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_5'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_6'] .      "<br>" .$row['spec_7'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_8'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_9'] . "<br>" .$row['spec_10'] . "<br>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['info_1'] . "<br>" . $row['info_2'] . "<br>" .$row['info_3'] . "<br>" .$row['info_4'] . "<br>" .$row['info_5'] . "<br>" .$row['info_6'] .      "<br>" .$row['info_7'] . "<br>" .$row['info_8'] . "<br>" .$row['info_9'] . "<br>" .$row['info_10'] . "<br>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['link_1'] . "<br>" .$row['link_2'] .  "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger' /></td>";  
        echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['product_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>"; //added 
    }
?>
    </table>
<?php 
}
else
{
    echo "<br><br>No Record Found";
}
?>
```

So what I did was copy this product page as it works, created a new featuredproducts.php and changed the relevant info to point to right table in database and changed the  tag info and took out the delete button as there is no need to delete just edit, new code below.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
 
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>
 
<?php 

require_once 'connect.php';

require_once 'viewfeaturedheader.php';

require_once 'previewheader.php';

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM featuredproducts";
$result = $con->query($sql); 

if( $result->num_rows > 0)

{ 
?>
    
<h2 style="margin-left: -29.5%;">List of all Products</h2>
    <table style="margin-left: -30%;" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Image</td>
            <td width="70px">EDIT</td>
        </tr>
        
        
<?php
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";  //added
        echo "<input type='hidden' value='". $row['featuredproduct_id']."'/>"; //added
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".'<img src="Images/', $row['image'], '" />' . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='editfeatured.php?id=".$row['featuredproduct_id']."' class='btn btn-info'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>"; //added 
    }
?>
    </table>
<?php 
}
else
{
    echo "<br><br>No Record Found";
    
}
?>
```

It seemed logical and simple enough, but it is not working.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the code for `editfeatured.php` to be able to help. This code shows how you draw the 'edit' link, but not what happens when you click it.

Comment: @droopsnoot You are totally right, am am just being a dumbass, I went to the editfeatured.php after I asked the question and saw I did nothing there so went and change all code to match and it worked. "facepalm". But thank you so much for getting back to me you would of solved my problem.